# Random name generator without duplicates in unity

Tags: c#, random

I'm trying to create a list which prints out a random name I've attached to a gameobject in unity. How would I go about stopping duplicates?

```
using TMPro;

public class Names : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<string> names = new List<string>();
    public TMP_Text text;

    private void Start()
    {
        string wordToDisplay = RandomWord();

        text.text = wordToDisplay;
    }

    private string RandomWord()
    {
        {
            string randomName = names[Random.Range(0, names.Count)];
                       
            return randomName;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What if you remove used name from collection? This will guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: you need to at least keep track of used names I would have thought

Comment: Realise that wanting to select random values without replacement is logically the same as *shuffling the list once* and just consuming values in order.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
private Stack<string> _randomNames = null;
private string RandomWord()
{
    if (_randomNames == null || _randomNames.Count == 0)
    {
        _randomNames = new Stack<string>(names.OrderBy(n => Random.Range(0, int.MaxValue)));
    }
    return _randomNames.Pop();
}
```

It's effectively ordering the list randomly and then picking a value one at a time.

Comment: Just something to note about this - if this is attached to multiple objects in the scene they will each be going through a separate copy of the list, so it won't stop duplication - this code would need to be on a name distribution object that is then shared with the Names behaviour (OPs code picked one name from a list, and then that code is added to multiple objects)

Answer (score 0):

As Uriil mentioned in the comment you could remove the new name from the list when you call RandomWord to guarantee uniqueness. Here is an example on how to achieve this:

```
private string RandomWord()
{
    int index = Random.Range(0, names.Count);
    
    string randomName = names[index];
    names.RemoveAt(index);
    
    return randomName;
}
```